# ILLink - unresolved assembly during dotnet publish

Tags: asp.net-core, ilmerge

I added the package `ILLink.Tasks 0.1.5-preview-1841731` to my `.net core 2.1` project, but I get these messages and no output. (TargetFramework is netcoreapp2.1)

My goal is to ship a product as self-contained application, so I want to strip down the files I need to ship.

## dotnet publish output

```
dotnet publish -c Release  -r win-x64  -o out
Microsoft (R)-Buildmodul, Version 15.7.179.6572 für .NET Core
**removed**
ILLINK : warning : unresolved assembly System.ServiceModel.Syndication [**removed**]
ILLINK : warning : unresolved assembly System.Threading.AccessControl [**removed**]
ILLINK : warning : unresolved assembly System.IO.Packaging [**removed**]
ILLINK : warning : unresolved assembly System.CodeDom [**removed**]
ILLINK : warning : unresolved assembly Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents [**removed**]
ILLINK : warning : unresolved assembly System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager [**removed**]
ILLINK : warning : unresolved assembly System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter [**removed**]
ILLINK : warning : unresolved assembly System.Diagnostics.EventLog [**removed**]
ILLINK : warning : unresolved assembly System.IO.Ports [**removed**]
ILLINK : warning : unresolved assembly System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController [**removed**]
ILLINK : warning : unresolved assembly System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData [**removed**]
ILLINK : warning : unresolved assembly System.Drawing.Common [**removed**]
ILLINK : warning : unresolved assembly System.Data.Odbc [**removed**]
```

## Net Core Version

```
.NET Core SDK (gemäß "global.json"):
Version:   2.1.300
Commit:    adab45bf0c

Laufzeitumgebung:
OS Name:     Windows
OS Version:  10.0.14393
OS Platform: Windows
RID:         win10-x64
Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.2
  Commit:  811c3ce6c0
```

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this?

Comment: No, sadly the microsoft mail adresse for illink is dead. Just waiting for .Net Core 3 and hoping this will be improved.